# Turn this integral into a Laplace transformation by Change of Variables

Tags: laplace-transform

Question from Advanced Engineering Mathematics - Greenberg. 
Page 268, section 5.4 question 6.

$C(T)$ = $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-0.0744v^2/T^2}p(v)dv$

is an approximate relation between frequency spectrum p(v) and the specific heat C(T) of a crystal, where T is the temperature.

Solve for $p(v)$ if $C(T) = T$.

Hint (given in book): By a suitable change of variables, the integral can be made to be a Laplace transform.

Spent hours on this one, got nowhere.

Looking for an appropriate change of variables to put $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-0.0744v^2/T^2}p(v)dv$ into the form:

$P(s) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st}p(t)dt$ - The Laplace Transform of $p(t)$. Then we can use the inverse table of the transformation to solve for $p(t)$.

Taking $s = -0.0744v/T^2$ doesn't seem to be very useful, because then the transformed function is of the form $P(-0.0744v/T^2) = T$, which is still a function of the variable $v$.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $−0.0744 v^22/T^2$ to be $-s t$.  Let us get rid of the square in $v^2$. We can take $u=v^2$, so $du=2v\,dv$. We substitute, and now we have 
$$
\int_0^\infty\,e^{−0.0744 u/T^2}\,\left(\frac1{2\sqrt u}\,p(\sqrt u)\right)\,du.
$$
This is the Laplace Transform of the function in brackets at the point $s=0.0744/T^2$. So your equation is now 
$$
T=F(0.0744/T^2).
$$
If we let $R=0.0744/T^2$, then $T=\sqrt{0.0744/R}$, and now the equation looks like 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{0.0744}}{\sqrt{R}}=F(R)
$$
Looking at the inverse Laplace Transform of $\sqrt a/\sqrt s$, we get that 
$$
\frac1{2\sqrt u}\,p(\sqrt u)=\frac{\sqrt{0.0744}}{\sqrt \pi\,\sqrt  u}.
$$
As $\sqrt u=v$, we get
$$
p(v)=\frac{2\times\sqrt{0.0744}}{\sqrt \pi}.
$$
It not that exciting that $p$ turns out to be constant...

Comment: Nice work, thank you! I went a little bit down a similar line, but the main issue I had getting started was forgetting that some function of a square root of u is still a function of u. So I couldn't work out how we were taking the Laplace transform of the function when we had e to the power of -su, and a function in terms of square root of u. You cleared that up nicely. The second part of the question is C(T) = Te^(-1/T), which I worked out using the method you gave. The second one is not a constant. :)